# Android audio effects not attaching to audio stream in real time once the stream has started

Tags: android, audio, stream, effects, audiotrack

I'm trying to make an app for Android which receives a PCM audio stream from a Raspberry Pi 4 using a TCP protocol. The app has to be able to apply audio effects in real time to this audio stream, like reverb, bassboost, virtualizer and loudness enhancer. At this point, the application is receiving the audio stream and is playing it back using AudioTrack. The problem is that these effects are not being applied to the audio stream with some buttons that I have set up in the UI.

I recently tested the reverb effect (PresetReverb) by applying if before I click on the button that enables the stream to begin, and it works. The problem is that the effect doesn't get disabled if I press the button again, so it stays forever until I restart the app. The other effects don't get enabled either once the stream has started so **it's not a problem from a specific audio effect**.

Note 1: the class that has the audiotrack loop runs in a thread, that is created by another class. The code for the audio effects is in this same thread but outside the loop for the AudioTrack.

Note 2:The code for the stream part of the app is shown. Hope someone can help since I haven't found many info of using Android audio effects so I don't have much knowledge about these.

```
class ThreadStartStream implements Runnable {
    byte [] buffer = new byte[4096];
    DataInputStream myDis = new DataInputStream(myBis);
    AudioTrack myAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(stream, sample, channel, encoding, BUFFER_SIZE, mode);
    
    PresetReverb myReverb = new PresetReverb(0, 0);
    BassBoost myBassBoost = new BassBoost(0, myAudioTrack.getAudioSessionId()); //Session ID = 0 deprecated
    Virtualizer myVirtualizer = new Virtualizer(0, myAudioTrack.getAudioSessionId());
    LoudnessEnhancer myLoudness = new LoudnessEnhancer(0);
    EnvironmentalReverb myEnvi = new EnvironmentalReverb (0 ,0);

    ThreadStartStream() throws IOException {
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //Reverb
        if(reverbEnable){
            myAudioTrack .attachAuxEffect(myReverb.getId());
            myReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEROOM);
            myReverb.setEnabled(true);
            myAudioTrack.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);

        } else{
            myReverb.setEnabled(false);
        } Log.d("AlertaMain", "myReverb.getEnabled: " + myReverb.getEnabled());

        //BassBoost
        if (bassBoostEnable) {
            myAudioTrack .attachAuxEffect(myBassBoost.getId());
            if (myBassBoost.getStrengthSupported()){
                myBassBoost.setStrength((short) 500);
            } else {
                Log.d("AlertaMain", "BassBosst strength NOT supported.");
            }
            myBassBoost.setEnabled(true);
            myAudioTrack.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
            Log.d("AlertaMain", "BassBosst strength supported: " + myBassBoost.getStrengthSupported());

        } else{
            myBassBoost.setEnabled(false);
        } Log.d("AlertaMain", "myBassBoost.getEnabled: " + myBassBoost.getEnabled());

        //Loudness enhancer
        if(loudnessEnable){
            myAudioTrack .attachAuxEffect(myLoudness.getId());
            myLoudness.setTargetGain(500); //500mB = 5dB
            myLoudness.setEnabled(true);
            myAudioTrack.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);

        } else{
            myLoudness.setEnabled(false);
        } Log.d("AlertaMain", "myReverb.getEnabled: " + myLoudness.getEnabled());

        //Virtualizer
        if(virtualizerEnable){
            myAudioTrack .attachAuxEffect(myVirtualizer.getId());
            if (myVirtualizer.getStrengthSupported()){
                myVirtualizer.setStrength((short) 500);
            } else {
                Log.d("AlertaMain", "Virtualizer strength NOT supported");
            }
            myVirtualizer.setEnabled(true);
            myAudioTrack.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);

        } else{
            myVirtualizer.setEnabled(false);
        } Log.d("AlertaMain", "myReverb.getEnabled: " + myVirtualizer.getEnabled());

        try {
            if(socket.getInputStream() != null){
                int i = 0;
                while (socket.getInputStream().read(buffer) != -1){ //Esta condición se puede cambiar por un botón
                    buffer [buffer.length-1-i] = myDis.readByte();
                    myAudioTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    myAudioTrack.play();
                    i++;
                }
                myAudioTrack.release();
                myDis.close();
                myBis.close();
                socket.close();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Buffer vacío", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("AlertaMain", "Buffer vacío: fuera del while loop");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Socket input stream vacío. Reinicie app.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("AlertaMain", "socket input stream vacío");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```